# Deleting a QWidget when closed

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qwidget

I have my main application `QWindow` where, when I press a QPushButton a new child window (a `QWidget`) pops up.  There are two ways of exiting the `QWidget` window:

1. Click the X in the top right hand corner, or
2. Click on the 'Finished' `QPushButton` I have in the `QWidget` window.

I would like to ensure that, when either method is used to exit the window, the `QWidget` is deleted.  I believe that I can ensure this in the second case by adding `self.deleteLater()` to the function called when the 'Finished `QPushButton` is clicked, but I am struggling to see how to do this in the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an attribute on the widget to do this:

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget)
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
```

Your "Finished" button then only has to call `self.close()` (which is equivalent to clicking the titlebar close button).